# Not able to download created excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, spring

Please check my code. There is no error. But still, I am not getting any excel downloaded. The console also shows no error and the sysout also shows the correct sizes of lists. 9 row data is coming from dao to this `tpaAuthList`. Please help.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadTpaPreAuthExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void downloadTpaPreAuthExcel(@RequestParam("typevalue") String typevalue,
        @RequestParam("idtypevalue") String idtypevalue, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            List<TpaPreAuthModel> tpaAuthList;
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=TpaPreAuth.xls");
            try {
                tpaAuthList = tpaPreAuthService.getTpaPreAuthSearchDataForExcel(typevalue,idtypevalue);
                System.out.println("tpaAuthList size in method-->"+tpaAuthList.size());
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("DataSheet");
                Map<String, Object[]> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                data.put(String.valueOf(1), new Object[]{"        TPA PRE AUTH LIST"});
                data.put(String.valueOf(2), new Object[]{""});
                data.put(String.valueOf(3), new Object[]{""});
                int i = 5;
               
                    data.put("4", new Object[]{"Transaction ID", "Patient Name", "Hospital Name", "Pre Auth Date", "RGHS Card No", "Minutes Elapsed"});
                    for (TpaPreAuthModel listBean : tpaAuthList) {
                        data.put(String.valueOf(i), new Object[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
                        i++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("For loop ended--");
    
                Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
                int rownum = 0;
                System.out.println("keyset size-->"+keyset.size());                 
                for (String key : keyset) {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                    Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
                    int cellnum = 0;
                    for (Object obj : objArr) {
                        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                        if (obj instanceof Date) {
                            cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                        } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
                            cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                        } else if (obj instanceof String) {
                            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                        } else if (obj instanceof Double) {
                            cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
                        } else if (obj instanceof Long) {
                            cell.setCellValue((Long) obj);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Ket set for loop ended--");
                OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Outstream--");
                workbook.write(outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
    
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: Close the `workbook`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "downloadTpaPreAuthExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Callable<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>> downloadTpaPreAuthExcel(
        @RequestParam("typevalue") String typevalue,
        @RequestParam("idtypevalue") String idtypevalue
    ) {
        return new Callable<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>>() {
            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> call() throws Exception {
                return toResponseBody(new Supplier<Workbook>() {

                    @Override
                    public Workbook get() {
                        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        List<TpaPreAuthModel> tpaAuthList;
                        try {
                            tpaAuthList = tpaPreAuthService.getTpaPreAuthSearchDataForExcel(typevalue, idtypevalue);
                            System.out.println("tpaAuthList size in method-->" + tpaAuthList.size());
                            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("DataSheet");
                            Map<String, Object[]> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                            data.put(String.valueOf(1), new Object[] { "        TPA PRE AUTH LIST" });
                            data.put(String.valueOf(2), new Object[] { "" });
                            data.put(String.valueOf(3), new Object[] { "" });
                            int i = 5;

                            data.put("4", new Object[] { "Transaction ID", "Patient Name", "Hospital Name",
                                    "Pre Auth Date", "RGHS Card No", "Minutes Elapsed" });
                            for (TpaPreAuthModel listBean : tpaAuthList) {
                                data.put(String.valueOf(i), new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
                                i++;
                            }
                            System.out.println("For loop ended--");

                            Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
                            int rownum = 0;
                            System.out.println("keyset size-->" + keyset.size());
                            for (String key : keyset) {
                                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                                Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
                                int cellnum = 0;
                                for (Object obj : objArr) {
                                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                                    if (obj instanceof Date) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                                    } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                                    } else if (obj instanceof String) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                                    } else if (obj instanceof Double) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
                                    } else if (obj instanceof Long) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((Long) obj);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("Ket set for loop ended--");
                            return workbook;
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                }, "TpaPreAuth.xlsx");
            }
        };

    }
    
    private ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> toResponseBody(Supplier<Workbook> workbookSupplier, String fileName) {
        Workbook workbook = workbookSupplier.get();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
            .body(new StreamingResponseBody() {
                @Override
                public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                    if (workbook != null) {
                        try (Workbook workbookRef = workbook) {
                            workbook.write(outputStream);
                            if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook ) {
                                ((SXSSFWorkbook) workbook).dispose();
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook ) {
                                ((SXSSFWorkbook) workbook).dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
     }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer @Mic. 
I have used your code. It is giving 500 error and saying that, "Asynchronous support must be enable".
Then I useed "Async" tag for this method and  "EnableAsync" tag for this controller class. 
Then there was no error. But excel not downloading. Even method also not executing.

Comment: I converted the method from POST to GET and I removed not used parameters and cleaned the code: could you try again?

Answer (score 0):

Close workbook before it become file. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#close--

For better

```java
HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
try {
    workbook = ...
    //....
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //...
}finally {
    workbook.close();
}
```